# How do I fire a blur event to change the value of a an input element with Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I want to write a test for an input form, but am unable to fire a Blur event.

I have a react component containing the following input element:

```
<input
  id='email'
  onBlur={this.handleInputChange}
  name='email'
  type='text'
/>
```

I also have `email` in the state and a function defined that sets the state:

```
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  };
```

I have the following in my test file:

```
    const inputs = component.find('input');

    expect(inputs.length).toEqual(2);                             // test case passes
    inputs.at(0).simulate('blur', { target: { value: 'abc@hello' } });
    expect(inputs.at(0).props().value).toEqual('abc@hello');      //test fails
```

The test also fails if I try to simulate a *change* event:
`inputs.at(0).simulate('change', { target: { value: 23 } });`

In both cases, I get the error:

```
    Expected: "abc@hello"
    Received: undefined
```

It seems that my code doesn't fire the event. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: This also fails, and gives the follow error: 
```Property 'value' does not exist on type 'ReactWrapper<HTMLAttributes, any, Component<{}, {}, any>>'.
```

Comment: check the state's email property instead. posted one answer you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

you refer to the `props().value` in your test
and the input element doesn't have such a property.
so you need to add `value` prop to input

```
<input
  id='email'
  onBlur={this.handleInputChange}
  name='email'
  type='text'
  value={this.state.email}
/>
```

in order to test the expected props value,
you need to force rerender the component to reflect the new value.
in `Enzyme`, we can do that by using `wrapper.setProps({})`.
you can pass the desired value `wrapper.setProps({value: 'abc@hello'})` or just an empty object, the purpose here is to cause a rerender.

```
const inputs = component.find('input');

expect(inputs.length).toEqual(2);  // test case passes
inputs.at(0).simulate('blur', { target: { value: 'abc@hello' } });

// setProps should be called on the shallow or root wrapper.
component.setProps({}); // cause rerender.
expect(inputs.at(0).props().value).toEqual('abc@hello');  // test should pass
```

Comment: I thought, props have access to the value attribute by default.
I just tried this, the test still failed; though this time it received a value of `""`  instead of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

As your component sets the state's email property. You can have a check on component's state like:

```
expect(component.state().email).toEqual('abc@hello');
```

Comment: This does work correctly, thanks! But just for clarity, could you please why input's target.value doesn't get changed? I thought testing is supposed to emulate a user, so I should not be accessing the state directly.

Comment: I am not sure but as other answer suggests might be the issue. setState takes a bit of time due to its async nature. So might be it gets called before it sets the value to the input. Although Unit testing is to test the behavior and clicking on buttons etc are part of e2e tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class YourComponent extends Component {
  state = {email: ''};

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  };
   
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        id='email'
        onBlur={this.handleInputChange}
        name='email'
        type='text'
        value={this.state.email}
      />
    );
  }
}
 export default YourComponent;
```

**Test file**

```
    describe("Blur test", () => {
      it("input component", () => {
        const component = mount(<YourComponent />);
        let inputs = component.find('input');
        const inputValue =  'abc@hello';
        inputs.at(0).simulate('blur', { target: { value: inputValue } });
    
        inputs = component.find('input');
        console.log(inputs.debug());// you will get updated value here
        expect(inputs.props().value).toEqual(inputValue);
      });
    });
```